# What is the difference between *(.text) vs *(.text*) in c linker?

Tags: c, linker-scripts

I want to know the exact difference between two:

```
*(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
*(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
```

Note that this exist for others like .bss, .rodata .etc, what about them?
I know .text is the code, .dada initialized variables ... and * is wildcard .I can see in arm-none-eabi-objdump that functions are in form of .text* format but I didn't find the reference to explain exactly them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `*(.text)` will include only objects stored in the `.text` segment.
2. `*(.text*)` will include only objects stored in the segment having `.text` at the beginning of its name (* works like a wildcard).

It is especially important if the compiler places functions in its own sections to remove unused ones.

If you compile, asking the compiler to place functions in separate sections you will have for example ***`.text.baseShouldLoadMeshGUI`*** section containing the ***`baseShouldLoadMeshGUI`*** function.

It is needed if you want to discard unused functions as the `ld` linker can only discard sections, not the particular functions from the sections.

Example:

```
 .text.baseShouldLoadUpMesh
                0x0000000000000000        0x4 ./Apps/G4-MC3/baseG4MC3.o
 .text.baseShouldLoadMeshGUI
                0x0000000000000000        0x4 ./Apps/G4-MC3/baseG4MC3.o
 .text.baseTriggerUSBDStart
                0x0000000000000000       0x94 ./Apps/G4-MC3/baseG4MC3.o
 .text.GUI_ShowNewSkin
                0x0000000000000000       0x54 ./Apps/G4-MC3/baseG4MC3.o
```

More detailed explanation:

> -ffunction-sections instructs gcc to place each function (including static ones) in its own section named .text.function_name instead of
> placing all functions in one big .text section.
> At link time, ld normally coalesces all such sections into one output
> section .text again. It is achieved by having *(.text.*) spec along
> with *(.text) spec in built-in linker scripts.
>
> -fdata-sections is analogous: it places each global or static variable into .data.variable_name, .rodata.variable_name or .bss.variable_name.

Segments names are implementation-defined, but the very common names:

- `.text` - code
- `.rodata` - **R**ead **O**nly data
- `.data` - initialized static storage data
- `.bss` - not initialized static storage data

Comment: Thanks but I think that I've missed to tell I wanted to know the segments content.

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd I have explained in the answer - if you compile asking the compiler to place functions in the separate sections you will have for example `.text.baseShouldLoadMeshGUI` section containing `baseShouldLoadMeshGUI` function.

Comment: I mean why .text and .text* must exist, they've tried to seprate what? maybe constant data and functions, am I right?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd i have explained it. if you dod not understand it - simple always add it

Comment: You've embarressed me for such clean answer (upvote), but I know difference between .rodata and .text. Could you please expand them to more specific `.text`|`.text*`, `.rodata`|`.rodata*` ...

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd I cant explain it simpler than I did. And I did not want to embarrass you at all.  Again without `\*` at the end the linker would not consider .text_something section as part of the .text section. Same applies to the .rodata, .data & .bss